# hide subreport using SSRS expression is not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a [image: main report] called Report 1 and a sub report. [image: The sub report] is embedded in one of the rows in the main report. I am trying to hide the sub report from showing `Milestone_ID` value as null. I used the expression on the visibility property of the table I used on sub report.

I am using `=iif(not IsNothing(Fields!Milestone_ID.Value),false,true)` expression

The problem is, [image: when I preview the report for first time it works fine]. The heading of the sub report is hidden but when I go back and forth and come back to the same report in report viewer [image: it is not working.]

Comment: Please attach some screenshots of your report in design view as well as when rendered, showing it both working and not per your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this behavior before but normally when I want to show/hide a subreport, I calculate the visibility in the main dataset and then simply set the visibility of the subreport object or table row in the MAIN report. In other words, I don't change anything in the actual subreport design.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the expression I sued to =CountRows() = 0 on the visibility property of the table on the sub report. Now It is working as expected. 
 when the sub report is embedded under the main report the expression was not finding the field MilestoneId which I set in the expression.